# how to handle consolidate reporting of multiple table with same structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

We are creating client wise multiple table with same structure to reduce load of operation transaction

but now we required consolidate reporting of all client. what is the best method to handle this situation ?

each table has 200k - 300k rows and more than 100 clients are available (100 Tables)

can I create dump table ?  or any other methods

Comment: ms-sql-server or mysql?

Comment: "2 to 3 lakh rows" - how much is it?

Comment: 0.2 or 0.3 million,  database -ms-sql server

Comment: You are creating separate tables for each client?  That's rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to offload reporting from OLTP database, especially in situations like this.

It would mean to create a single-table data warehouse in another database, denormalize it and index as you wish, and load it at some appropriate interval.

This way you'll get both the speed of reporting and won't slow the inserts down. Only have to agree with the customer about the latency of the data.

Answer (score 0):

use a view for your reporting needs:

```
create view omni
    as
select 1 as client_id
     , *
  from tab_1
 union all
select 2 as client_id
     , *
  from tab_2
 union all
   [...]
```

Comment: its ok.  its very slow any

Comment: and we have dynamic table naming

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic table naming? do the names change over time? maybe you would like to be a little more specific about what you need and give all the information that you have concerning your problem.

Comment: sorry not dynamic table name i want to select random client table while reporting i want to take report of some client only